# Document null when testing with Testing Library

Tags: react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a single component in my react app and getting the following error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of null

      20 | 
      21 |     resize = () => {
    > 22 |         const contentWidth = document.getElementById('root').clientWidth;
```

Here's the test:

```
import React from 'react'
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import reducer from '../store/reducer';
import Navigation from '../App/layout/AdminLayout/Navigation'

const store = createStore(reducer);

describe('Menu', () => {
  it('Estate Planning points to classic estate planning page', () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Navigation />
        </Provider>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    screen.debug()
  })
})
```

I tried with defining the container `render(..., { container: document.body})`, but got the same error.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because your document does not contain an element with id "root" when running a test with `react-testing-library`. This is likely because `react-testing-library` renders your component to a different container than `ReactDOM` (which is used to run your application).

## The Problem

Let's look at a typical React application setup.

```html
<!-- public/index.html -->
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
// src/index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```js
// src/components/App.js
import React from "react";

const App = () => <div>Hello World!</div>;

export default App;
```

As we can see, `index.js` looks for an HTML element with an id of "root" and renders our `App` component inside that element. We can confirm that is happening by inspecting the element in your browser's developer tools:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div>Hello World!</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, let's write a simple test, and see what the DOM looks like.

```js
// src/components/App.test.js
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";

test("renders the component", () => {
  render(<App />);
  screen.debug();
});
```

`screen.debug()` prints the DOM for debugging purposes. We can see that it does not include an element with id "root":

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      Hello World!
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

So the DOM container is slightly different for your test vs. runtime.

## The Solution

One way to fix this problem is to refactor your code not to be dependent on the "root" element. Another option is to tell `react-testing-library` to render your component in a custom container. Here is an example of what that might look like:

```js
// src/components/App.test.js
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";

test("renders the component in a specific container", () => {
  const container = document.createElement("div");
  container.id = "root";

  render(<App />, { container: document.body.appendChild(container) });
  screen.debug();
});
```

Now, we can see an element with id of "root" in the DOM, so your component should be able to find that element.

```html
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div>
      Hello World!
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```